# Prove the inequality

Tags: inequality, fractions, substitution, tangent-line-method

Thesis:
$$\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1}+\frac{c}{c^2+1}\leq 9/10$$ 
Assumptions:
$$a+b+c=1$$
$$ a,b,c \geq -\frac{3}{4}$$
Can someone give me a hint? I suppose there is a tricky way, not using derivatives of the function of two variables

Comment: I think I asked this on AoPS a long time ago, and the hint was Cauchy-Schwarz. It may have been the Titu form of CS.

Comment: Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095843/find-the-maximum-value-of-the-expression the same inequality is shown *without* assuming the lower bound on $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{x}{3}$, $b=\frac{y}{3}$ and $c=\frac{z}{3}$.

Hence, $x+y+z=3$, $\{x,y,z\}\subset[-\frac{9}{4},+\infty)$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x^2+9}\leq\frac{3}{10}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{10}-\frac{x}{x^2+9}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(x-1)(x-9)}{x^2+9}+\frac{4}{5}(x-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-1)^2(4x-9)}{x^2+9}\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Clever as always - I enjoy your solutions to inequalities here and on AoPS.

Comment: @Sean Roberson Thank you!

Comment: @Ryszard Eggink Because $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x-1)=x+y+z-3=0$.

Comment: Of course, i just figured it out and deleted my comment Thanks, anyway

Comment: @Ryszard Eggink Welcome!